# Right Align Top Tabs in JavaFX

Tags: css, tabs, javafx, right-justified

Is it possible to right align tabs at the top of a TapPane?  I'm referring to the whole set of tabs and not the label text inside a tab.

I've already tried something like this:

```
#main-tabs .tab-pane:top *.tab-header-area {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER_RIGHT;
}
```

as well as tricking it with CSS padding:

```
#main-tabs .tab-pane:top *.tab-header-area {
    -fx-padding: 0.416667em 100% 0.0em 0%;
}
```

Neither appears to work.  I can manually change the left padding using fixed sizes but that doesn't help on a resizable stage.  I can't seem to figure out how to keep the tabs right justified.

Answer (score 2):

if you using (scene builder) you can do it through the following steps:

1. Select the *TabPane*
2. In the *Properties* find *Node Orientation* and select (*Right to Left*)